# Feminine form of “son” when used as term of endearment

Tags: grammatical-gender, hypocorisms

It seems natural and appropriate for an older man to call a non-relative boy/young man “son” to convey endearment. Although I’m not sure, I think it’s unofficially reserved for men’s use only (the older person is male).

However, if he younger person was female, “daughter” seems awkward.

Is there a analogous term of endearment for young females? If so, it is reserved for older women’s use? Or is “daughter” used?

Comment: This is mostly a matter of use, and use varies. "Sister" is a common term, but is clearly not analogous to "son".

Comment: The only two really natural-sounding options that I can think of (_girl_ and _dear_) are quite likely to come off as patronising in the wrong situation, so I wouldn’t use them unless you know for sure whether the situation would allow it.

Comment: It may be natural and have a long history that this use is not uncommon from an older to a younger man, but there has been a trend to consider 'son' patronizing, almost to the same extent as [the practically insulting 'boy'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy#Race). Also 'unofficially reserved' isn't how language works. Women _tend_ not to use 'son' (except maybe in the US South?), and men _tend_ not to use terms of endearment with other men.

Comment: Previously asked as *[Familiar form of address for a young, subordinate, woman that connotes respect (Female equivalent to 'Son')](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225259)* Also see *[Why is a young man called “son,” but a young woman is never called “daughter”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321072)* and *[Female equivalent of 'son' to call kids](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342999)*; of related interest is *[Do people actually address their male child “Son” rather than a name, in real life English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410288)*

Comment: This question also asks about who can *use* the term (older males or females) in addition to finding the term itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Lass" or "Lassie"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lass) are commonly used in dialects in the north of England and Scotland to address girls and young women in a friendly way, although they are sometimes considered sexist so I'd be wary of using them. ([Daily Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/relationships/11643973/Mind-your-language-the-words-and-phrases-that-mark-you-out-as-a-sexist.html))

I don't think there's a term of endearment or form of address common across all English-speaking regions, but terms of endearment still tend to be quite local or region-specific.

Comment: I'm going with "Lass", rather than the doubly-diminutive "Lassie" (term understood in Australia too, at least by the older half of the population)